# Yodlee: How to delete every user's linked accounts in a single API call

Tags: python-3.x, yodlee

How can delete all of user's linked accounts without having to make multiple API calls for each account or unregistering the user? I currently using documented `/accounts/` endpoint to delete each one however sending a separate requests for each deletion takes far too long for users with multiple accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can unregister the user which effectively deletes all of the user’s accounts.

Comment: I want to keep the user after the accounts have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the providerAccount and it will delete all associated accounts.
e.g., DELETE [https://developer.yodlee.com/providerAccounts/{providerAccountId}](https://developer.yodlee.com/providerAccounts/%7BproviderAccountId%7D)